# Trying to determine DTMF from .wav file

Tags: matlab

So I am trying to determine the numbers dialed in a DTMF wave file by reading the [x, y] co-ordinates of the Fourier analysis plot. The numbers are: 251216. Here is my Matlab code for the same:

```
% Tone Dialling %
[y,Fs] = audioread('tones.wav');
n = length(y);
p = abs(fft(y));
f = (Fs/n)*(0:n-1);
plot(f,p);
axis([500 1400 0 1000])
xlabel('f(Hz)')
title('Power')
```

This corresponds to the following plot:

[image]

[image]

Now this should have 6 peaks, but doesn't! Where am I wrong? The clip is a 6second clip, pulse being played after every 1 second.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each tone in the DTMF signal is comprised of tones made of two specific frequencies.

```
        1209 Hz 1336 Hz 1477 Hz 1633 Hz
697 Hz    1       2       3       A
770 Hz    4       5       6       B
852 Hz    7       8       9       C  
941 Hz    *       0       #       D
```

If you take a DTMF signal of the sequence `555555` you will only see the two frequencies that comprise the tone of the number `5` in your fft plot.

[image: DTMF Signal 555555]

In your case your tones are made up of the following frequencies:

- 1: 697 Hz, 1209 Hz
- 2: 697 Hz, 1336 Hz
- 5: 770 Hz, 1336 Hz
- 6: 770 Hz, 1477 Hz

So 4 unique frequencies. Hence the four peaks in your signal. Tones 1 and 2 share frequency 697 Hz, tones 2 and 5 share frequency 1336 Hz, and tones 5 and 6 share frequency 770 Hz in their respective creation.

The amplitude of your plot should be giving you an indication of how often the frequency was used in any of the tones:

[image: fft-plot of DTMF signal 251216]

You cut off your plot at 1400 Hz, which is an error, because the DTMF tone 6 has a component at 1477 Hz.